# Select column using different WHERE clause from a different table

Tags: sql

Like many questions that have been asked on here, I need to be able to select the same column twice, using 2 different WHERE clauses. Unfortunately, there is a problem as I am also trying to fix another common problem in that, due to the WHERE clause, not all the cells are showing when I use COUNT(), even when using LEFT JOIN.

So there are 2 problems. First, the WHERE clause is removing one of the options where there is a NULL, despite a LEFT JOIN.

Second, I cannot merge 2 queries into one due to the WHERE clause.

I have tried using 'CASE WHEN' with the COUNT() inside and outside, sub-queries, OUTER APPLY and UNION. None of them show what I need.

So my 1st table shows students and their school houses:

```
Table - Houses

StudentID | House
---------------------
    1     |  A
    2     |  B
    3     |  C
    4     |  D
    5     |  A
    6     |  B
    7     |  C
    8     |  D
```

The second table shows house points:

```
Table - Points
StudentID | House | PointAwardedDate
------------------|-------------------
    1     |  A    |      01/04/2019 10:04:00
    1     |  A    |      17/05/2019 11:25:00
    1     |  A    |      17/06/2019 12:58:00
    2     |  B    |      02/02/2019 08:54:00
    3     |  C    |      03/03/2019 15:46:00
    4     |  D    |      17/06/2019 13:14:00
    5     |  A    |      05/06/2019 15:34:00
    6     |  B    |      01/02/2019 12:32:00
    7     |  C    |      17/06/2019 11:57:00
    8     |  D    |      15/04/2019 09:24:00
    8     |  D    |      17/06/2019 09:45:00
```

Using the following Code, I can pick out the awards that have been given since last Sunday (16/06/2019) and show how many have been awarded to each house:

```
SELECT
Houses.House,
COUNT(Points.StudentID) AS PointsCount
FROM Houses
LEFT JOIN Points
ON Houses.STudentID = Points.StudentID
WHERE Points.PointsAwardedDate >= (SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6))
GROUP BY Houses.House
```

Which shows

```
House  |  PointsCount
-------|--------------
  A    |      1
  C    |      1
  D    |      2
```

PROBLEM 1: I need to show that table as such:

```
House  |  PointsCount
-------|--------------
  A    |      1
  B    |      0
  C    |      1
  D    |      2
```

Problem 2 - We need to show another column with the points count for the entire school year. So the code we have (which works) is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Houses.House,
COUNT(Points.StudentID) AS PointsCountYear
FROM Houses
LEFT JOIN Points
ON Houses.STudentID = Points.StudentID
WHERE Points.PointsAwardedDate >= (
    SELECT 
        TOP 1 Points.PointsAwardedDate
    FROM TblSchoolManagementTermDates
    WHERE Points.PointsAwardedDate <= 
        CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE())
            AND intTerm = 1
        ORDER BY intSchoolYear DESC)
AND txtDate <= (
    SELECT TOP 1 txtFinishDate
    FROM TblSchoolManagementTermDates
    WHERE txtFinishDate >= 
        CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE())
        ORDER BY intSchoolYear ASC)
GROUP BY Pups.txtAcademicHouse
```

The term dates here are Sept 1 2018 - Aug 31 2019

This pulls out the following table:

```
House  |  PointsCountYear
-------|-----------------
  A    |      4
  B    |      2
  C    |      2
  D    |      3
```

We need to be able to combine the 2 together so our final table looks like this:

```
House  |  PointsCount |  PointsCountYear
-------|--------------|-----------------
  A    |      1       |      4
  B    |      0       |      2
  C    |      1       |      2
  D    |      2       |      3
```

We understand that the problem for the first part lies in the fact that the WHERE clause is filtering out any data for House B and so it is not showing even with the LEFT JOIN, but we are unsure how to present this in another way while still retaining the correct data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Move the where predicates to the join predicates. Also, you should decide which DBMS you are working with as mysql <> sql server.

Comment: Note that the House column in your Points table is not needed, and can only cause trouble if it gets out of sync with the other table. Unless students can change houses, in which case your Houses table should be removed instead.

Comment: Apologies, good spot @Jerry, There shouldn't be a house column in the Points table. No idea why I put it in there. Monday morning thing I reckon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  h.House,
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN p.PointsAwardedDate >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END)  AS PointsCount,
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN p.PointsAwardedDate >= '2018-09-01' AND p.PointsAwardedDate < '2019-09-01'  THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS PointsCountYear
FROM Houses AS h
LEFT JOIN Points AS p
ON h.STudentID = p.StudentID
GROUP BY h.House
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18dabbd6a629c48d98fb467dcfd2e99a).
Results:

```
> House | PointsCount | PointsCountYear
> :---- | ----------: | --------------:
> A     |           1 |               4
> B     |           0 |               2
> C     |           1 |               2
> D     |           2 |               3
```

Comment: This is the one! Removing the queries and changing from COUNT() to SUM() has cracked it. Thanks forpas

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer for SQLServer:
A possible solution of problem 1:

```
CREATE TABLE #HOUSES
(
  STUDENT_ID INT NOT NULL
, HOUSE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #HOUSES  VALUES (1, 'A')
, (2, 'B')
, (3, 'C')
, (4, 'D')
, (5, 'A')
, (6, 'B')
, (7, 'C')
, (8, 'D');

CREATE TABLE #POINTS
(
  STUDENT_ID INT NOT NULL
, HOUSE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
, POINTAWARDEDDATE DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #POINTS  VALUES 
(1, 'A', '01/04/2019 10:04:00'), 
(1, 'A', '17/05/2019 11:25:00'), 
(1, 'A', '17/06/2019 12:58:00'), 
(2, 'B', '02/02/2019 08:54:00'), 
(3, 'C', '03/03/2019 15:46:00'), 
(4, 'D', '17/06/2019 13:14:00'), 
(5, 'A', '05/06/2019 15:34:00'), 
(6, 'B', '01/02/2019 12:32:00'), 
(7, 'C', '17/06/2019 11:57:00'), 
(8, 'D', '15/04/2019 09:24:00'), 
(8, 'D', '17/06/2019 09:45:00')
;

SELECT H.HOUSE
    , COUNT(P.POINTAWARDEDDATE) AS POINTSCOUNT
FROM
(
SELECT HOUSE
FROM #HOUSES
GROUP BY HOUSE) H
LEFT JOIN #POINTS P
ON H.HOUSE = P.HOUSE
AND P.POINTAWARDEDDATE >= (SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6))
GROUP BY H.HOUSE
```

Result:

```
HOUSE, POINTSCOUNT
A   1
B   0
C   1
D   2
```

Comment: This looks good, but unfortunately as i mentioned in the comment above, I made a mistake. There is no House column in the Points table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT h.house
    , COUNT(P.PointsAwardedDate) AS POINTSCOUNT
FROM
(
SELECT StudentId,house
FROM HOUSES
) H
LEFT JOIN POINTS P
ON H.[StudentId] = P.StudentId
AND P.[PointsAwardedDate] >= (SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6))
GROUP BY h.house
```